# Idiomatic Wicket way of serving resources from Amazon S3

Tags: wicket

What is the Wicket way of serving user-uploaded assets from AWS S3?

Requirements:

- No direct requests from browser to S3; all traffic is proxied through our servers;
- Allow assets to be cached by the browser with cache busting (either via checksums or a `version` field in the database);
- Asset are served to authorized users only.

I can think of the following solutions:

1. A single SharedResource for all resources that parses the URL and streams the assets:

   ```
   // resource definition:
   mountResources("/assets/${path}", new ResourceReference("assets") {
       public IResource getResource() {
           return new AbstractResource() {
               public ResourceResponse newResourceResponse(RequestAttribute attributes) {
                   String path = attributes.getParameters().get("path").toString()
                   // request S3 and stream the content
                   // handle caching / busting by hand
               } 
           }
       }
   })

   // Usage:
   page.add(new Image("image", new SharedResourceReference("assets"), new PageParameters().add("path", "image.jpg"))
   ```
2. Create a new ResourceReference for each asset and pass it directly to image. Plug into Wicket's caches by letting the Resource implement IStaticCacheableResource:

   ```
   class S3ResourceReference extends ResourceReference {
       private String path;
       public S3ResourceReference(String path) { ... }
       public IResource getResource() {
           return new S3Resource(path);
       }
   }
   class S3Resource extends AbstractResource implements IStaticCacheableResource {
       public S3ResourceStream getResourceStream() {
           S3Object object = getObject(path);
           return new S3ResourceStream(object);
       }
       public ResourceResponse newResourceResponse(Attributes attributes) {
           S3ResourceStream stream = getResourceStream();
           // populate response
       }
   }

   class S3ResourceStream extends AbstractResourceStream {
       S3ResourceStream(S3Object object) {
           // ...
       }

       public InputStream getInputStream() { return object.objectContent }
       // override metadata methods
   }

   // Usage:
   page.add(new Image("image"), new S3ResourceReference("image.jpg"));
   ```

Which of these approaches look more idiomatic?

Are there any pitfalls with usage of IStaticCacheableResource in the second snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the differences in those two approaches:

**Page instance locking**

- In 1) the requests for the resources are made to an application scoped resource
- In 2) the request is to a page scoped resource

In the second case Wicket will lock the access to the page instance during the serving of the resource. For that reason I prefer using the application scoped resource.

**IStaticCacheableResource**

If the resource implements this interface then Wicket will mangle the produced url to the resource and will add something like `-123456789` in its file name. This hash is the resource modification time in DEVELOPMENT mode and its MD5 checksum in PRODUCTION mode. This helps for caching.

I hope you realize that you can use a mix of 1) and 2) - an application scoped resource reference + IStaticCacheableResource.

One more thing: I usually use `new MyResourceReference()` instead of `new SharedResourceReference("the-name")`.

Comment: "In 2) the request is to a page scoped resource" -- is that the same scope as the one specified in ResourceReference's constructor parameters?

Comment: No. By this I mean that Wicket needs to lock the access to the page instance, then find the Image in the component tree, and then find the resource references by this Image. During that request you won't be able to use any (Ajax)Link in the page. In 1) the request is to a shared resource and there is no locking at all.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies things a bit! So, it wouldn't be a stretch to use IStaticCacheableResource for user uploads such as avatars etc?

Comment: As I said above: you **can** mix application-scoped resources with IStaticCacheableResource.